# I got many duplicates with this function

Tags: php

I know something wrong with this function. It is supposed to return an array with 12 keys and values but it returns 60. The problem should be the foreach loop. Everytime the if loop is false, it passes a value to $result. Can anyone tell me how to make it right?

```
function getFinaluserElearningLesson($array1, $array2){
 $result = array();
for($i = 0; $i<count($array1); $i++){
foreach($array2 as $lesson2){

  if($array1[$i]['lesson'] == $lesson2['lesson_id'] && $array1[$i]['user_id'] == $lesson2['user_id']){
    $result[] = array(
       'first_name' => $array1[$i]['first_name'],
       'last_name' => $array1[$i]['last_name'],
       'date_of_birth' => $array1[$i]['date_of_birth'],
       'user_id' => $array1[$i]['user_id'],
       'client_id' => $array1[$i]['client_id'],
       'lesson' => $array1[$i]['lesson'],
       'lessonName' => $array1[$i]['lessonName'],
       'completion' => 'Completed'
    );
  }else{
    $result[] = array(
       'first_name' => $array1[$i]['first_name'],
       'last_name' => $array1[$i]['last_name'],
       'date_of_birth' => $array1[$i]['date_of_birth'],
       'user_id' => $array1[$i]['user_id'],
       'client_id' => $array1[$i]['client_id'],
       'lesson' => $array1[$i]['lesson'],
       'lessonName' => $array1[$i]['lessonName'],
       'completion' => 'Incomplete'
    );
  }
}

}
return $result;
}
```

The output of array1 and array2 is:

```
array(12) {
[0]=>
  array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(3) "Bob"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(6) "Gorsky"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1954-04-27"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "1701011"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(3) "222"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(6) "Asthma"
 }
[1]=>
  array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(3) "Bob"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(6) "Gorsky"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1954-04-27"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "1701011"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(2) "69"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(23) "Cardiac Catheterization"
}
 [2]=>
  array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(3) "Bob"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(6) "Gorsky"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1954-04-27"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "1701011"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(3) "308"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(38) "CyberKnife Radiosurgery For Brain AVMs"
}
[3]=>
  array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(3) "Bob"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(6) "Gorsky"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1954-04-27"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "1701011"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(2) "50"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(47) "Durable Power of Attorney for Health Care (DPA)"
}
[4]=>
  array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(3) "Bob"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(6) "Gorsky"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1954-04-27"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "1701011"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(2) "91"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(12) "Heart Attack"
}
[5]=>
  array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(4) "Alex"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(10) "Wilczewski"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1989-05-27"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2602204"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(3) "500"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(33) "Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm Surgery"
}
[6]=>
 array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(4) "Alex"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(10) "Wilczewski"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1989-05-27"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2602204"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(1) "1"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(19) "Cholesterol Control"
}
[7]=>
 array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(4) "Alex"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(10) "Wilczewski"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1989-05-27"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2602204"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(1) "5"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(16) "Types of Doctors"
}
[8]=>
 array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(4) "Alex"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(2) "Hu"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1983-09-14"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2685058"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(3) "500"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(33) "Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm Surgery"
}
[9]=>
 array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(4) "Alex"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(2) "Hu"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1983-09-14"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2685058"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(3) "116"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(4) "Acne"
}
[10]=>
 array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(4) "Alex"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(2) "Hu"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1983-09-14"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2685058"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(3) "122"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(5) "Burns"
}
[11]=>
 array(7) {
   ["first_name"]=>
   string(4) "Alex"
   ["last_name"]=>
   string(2) "Hu"
   ["date_of_birth"]=>
   string(10) "1983-09-14"
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2685058"
   ["client_id"]=>
   string(2) "71"
   ["lesson"]=>
   string(3) "546"
   ["lessonName"]=>
   string(60) "Peripherally Inserted Central Catheter (PICC) for Outpatient"
  }
}







 array(5) {
 [0]=>
  array(2) {
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(6) "951301"
   ["lesson_id"]=>
   string(2) "35"
 }
[1]=>
 array(2) {
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "1700981"
   ["lesson_id"]=>
   string(2) "35"
 }
[2]=>
 array(2) {
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2585455"
   ["lesson_id"]=>
   string(2) "25"
 }
[3]=>
 array(2) {
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2602204"
   ["lesson_id"]=>
   string(3) "500"
 }
[4]=>
  array(2) {
   ["user_id"]=>
   string(7) "2642677"
   ["lesson_id"]=>
   string(3) "180"
 }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your input? `print_r` $array1 and 2 for us please.

Comment: what does count($array1) * count($array2) output?

Comment: @uBio: I'm guessing that's rhetorical, because we know the answer is 60

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the inner if() DRASTICALLY by doing this:

```
if($array1[$i]['lesson'] == $lesson2['lesson_id'] && $array1[$i]['user_id'] == $lesson2['user_id']){
    $completion = 'Complete';
} else {
    $completion = 'Incomplete';
}
$result[] = array(
   'first_name' => $array1[$i]['first_name'],
   'last_name' => $array1[$i]['last_name'],
   'date_of_birth' => $array1[$i]['date_of_birth'],
   'user_id' => $array1[$i]['user_id'],
   'client_id' => $array1[$i]['client_id'],
   'lesson' => $array1[$i]['lesson'],
   'lessonName' => $array1[$i]['lessonName'],
   'completion' => $completion // <---- the **ONLY** difference between the two versions
);
```

As far as your "duplication" problem... I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this. You're running a nested loop, with 5 outer and 12 inner members, which gives your 60 array entries. Since you're assigning something to `$result` inside the inner loop, no matter WHAT the `if()` condition returns, that'll produce 60 assignments.

If you don't want the 'false' ones to happen, then don't do anything in the `else` clause of your code.

Comment: It looks like he wants to loop through all the "lessons" and flag all the matches as complete, and the rest as incomplete. If one array has 5 members, and the other has 12, and those 5 "overlap" with 5 in the 12, then I'm thinking he wants the output to be 5 complete and 7 incomplete for a total of 12.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But your code doesn't solve the problem. Because it is still within the foreach loop and still got 60 results

Comment: Mark, you are right. I still want 12 result returned. But how do I do that?